# Duplicate Key in Repeater Error [ngRepeat:dupes]

Tags: angularjs, node.js, search, angularjs-ng-repeat, live

I'm guessing I'm getting an imaging error. I not sure of the source of the mistake.

Note: Sometimes work smoothly, I often encounter this error.

**Form:**

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-app='afApp' ng-controller='afController'
     style="background: #F8F8F8;padding-top: 10px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <input type="search" size="40" ng-model="search" id="search"
                   autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
            <section ng-repeat="afData in afLoad | filter:search | limitTo:10"
                     ng-show='search' md-highlight-text="search">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                        <h2>{{afData.yil}}</h2>
                        <h3>{{afData.sik1}}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <p>{{afData.soru}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Console [Browser]:**

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=afData%20in%20afLoad%20%7C%20filter%3Asearch%20%7C%20limitTo%3A10&p1=string%3A%3C

**Console [SSH]:**

> (node:4015) [DEP0096] DeprecationWarning: timers.unenroll() is
>   deprecated. Please use clearTimeout instead.

Comment: You're not sure of the source for the `[ngRepeat:dupes]` error? Or you're not sure of the source for the `timers.unenroll() is deprecated` warning?

Comment: I'm not very good with Node.js @Lex

Comment: That doesn't really answer what I was asking, but a quick Google search turns up [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20261) for the deprecation warning. For the dupes error check out [the Angular docs on ng-repeat and duplicates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates). Also, that's a really old version of AngularJS that you're using.

Comment: I agree with you thank you for links. Also I'll try to upgrade the version. @Lex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would use a track by as stated in the error. at some point in your ng-repeat there must be objects that are not unique.

The following should suffice:

```
ng-repeat="afData in afLoad | filter:search | limitTo:10 track by $index"
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates

Comment: Search results are not displayed in the Google Chrome browser.. Sometimes at Opera and Mozilla. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: sounds like that should maybe be a new question. would need more info to answer.